# simple SQL Statement wrong

Tags: sql, database

I want to INSERT my Values only if the 2 conditions are not correct.

```
Insert INTO ArtikelNr VALUE (…)


WHERE "3434" NOT IN  (Select AriktelNr From Artikel) AND

isa_id = "3847"
```

What is wrong with this Code?

Comment: do you want to update value?

Comment: No It is a INSERT Statement. I wanted to shortcut,

Insert INTO ArtikelNr (a, b, c, d) VALUE ("a", "b", "c", "d")


WHERE "3434" NOT IN  (Select AriktelNr From Artikel) AND

isa_id = "3847"

Comment: I think you need share more details what do you want

Comment: What does the WHERE conditions has to do with your values you want to insert? It 's hard to see the logic in your attempted query.

Comment: So It does an Insert into the Table ArtikelNr but only if the Value "3434" is not exists in the table ArtikelNr AND the row isa_id does not contain the Value "3847"

Comment: That is not what you  have in your query, you are using a different table, `Artikel`. I think you need to have your conditions in a separate query that you execute before the insert.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT ... WHERE ... is not valid SQL.

WHERE only goes with SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate both values for a single record:

```
if not exists (select 1 from Artikel where AriktelNr='3434' and isa_id='3847')
begin
insert into Artikel (<columns>) values (<values>)
end
```

If you want to validate both values on different records:

```
if not exists (select 1 from Artikel where AriktelNr='3434')
begin
    if not exists (select 1 from Artikel where isa_id='3847')
    begin
    insert into Artikel (<columns>) values (<values>)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try and convert your "Values" part of the insert statement,

to an "Insert into Select" format, should work.

Sample:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (x int);
insert into test (x) values (1),(2),(3);

insert into test (x) 
select 2
where 2 not in (select x from test)
;
```